opencv-python: how to reduce the frame wait timer?
When trying to read a frame from the camera's IP by entering an incorrect link, the opencv waits 30 seconds and only then the code is executed further:
Link = 'RTSP_link'

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(TwoLink) # It stops here for 30 seconds

[ WARN:0@30.073]
Stream timeout triggered after 30068.467000 ms
If you know how to solve this problem, please help. Thank you in advance!

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see more code to see if there are issues earlier.

If the link is bad, why do you expect your code to proceed?

The problem is that it waits for 30 before throwing an exception.

The error has to time-out. Is the link local or HTTP?
